# jQuery animate img margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate 1 column of boxes aka placeholder.png down with margin-top but it animates all 9 of the boxes down instead of 3 in a column. Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/MgL3E/1

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("span").click(function() 
    {
        $("#1").animate(
        {
            "margin-top": "300px"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should layout columns first, eg

```
<div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
        <img class="hpbox" src="img/placeholder.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.column {
    float:left;
    width: 98px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgL3E/2/

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

- registering on span click, but theres no span element in your fiddle
- ids cannot start with a digit

This js runs fine for me, when changing `id="1"` to `id="t1"`. Testwise its registered on all img tags.. Replace it with whatever should cause the animation to spin in.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    $("#t1").animate({
      "margin-top": "300px"
    }, 1000);
  });
 });
```

Comment: how do i make it affect only column not all 3